# Change image of custom cell with UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, tableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I’ve created a custom cell that has `imageView` inside. I want to change the `image` of that `imageView` with the help of `UIImagePickerController`. When I check this function in the simulator, it doesn’t change anything. Can’t figure out the problem.

The property of the custom cell:

```swift
let imageOfPlace: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    return iv
}()
```

The cell in `tableView`:

```swift
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ImageOfPlaceViewCell.identifierOfImageOfPlaceCell) as! ImageOfPlaceViewCell
```

Functions of picker:

```swift
func chooseImagePickerController(source: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(source) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = source
        present(imagePicker, animated: true)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let myCell = ImageOfPlaceViewCell()
    myCell.imageOfPlace.image = info[.editedImage] as! UIImage
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new cell here:

```
let myCell = ImageOfPlaceViewCell()
```

Instead of that you need to change image of an existing cell. You need to get an existing cell object from the table. To do this you can use [`tableView.cellForRow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow), and pass there index path of your row.

I'm not sure about your table structure, but you also need to make sure that when you reload your table it won't disappear, so you can store picked image somewhere else to use next time in `cellForRowAt`.

```
var pickedImage: UIImage?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ImageOfPlaceViewCell.identifierOfImageOfPlaceCell) as! ImageOfPlaceViewCell
        cell.imageOfPlace.image = pickedImage
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    let image = info[.editedImage] as! UIImage
    pickedImage = image

    let myCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

    myCell?.imageOfPlace.image = info[.editedImage] as! UIImage

    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

p.s. Also I'm not sure what's this `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!` before your if, it's probably redundant(at least in case when you return cell from that `if`)

Comment: thanks so much! I’ve corrected the logic a lil bit